# Change date format to "d M - d M Y" if start date and end date include two months

Tags: php, html, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF repeater fields to output the dates in my WordPress site.

```
<h6 class="pegesus"><?php echo date("d", strtotime(get_sub_field('start_date'))).' - '.date("d M Y", strtotime(get_sub_field('end_date'))); ?></h6>
```

The format I'm getting is "`d - d M Y`" which is what I need.

But I want to change the format to "`d M - d M Y`" if the start date and end date fall in two months, e.g., 29th March to 5th April.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check months and use another formatting string

Comment: Can you show an example please ? I tried to do it but couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `IF` and another **date formatting**. Please follow below code::

```
<h6 class="pegesus">
<?php
if(date("m", strtotime(get_sub_field('start_date'))) != date("m", strtotime(get_sub_field('end_date'))))
{
    echo date("d M", strtotime(get_sub_field('start_date'))).' - '.date("d M Y", strtotime(get_sub_field('end_date')));
}
else
{
    echo date("d", strtotime(get_sub_field('start_date'))).' - '.date("d M Y", strtotime(get_sub_field('end_date')));
}
?>
</h6>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... You are a life saver.

Comment: @Damon please upvote the answer also if it helped you and for others.